# Questions and answers portlet for Liferay portal

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, portal

I need a portlet to post questions anonymously and answer them by a logged in user. Is there anything in Liferay library of portlets that I could use?

Ideally I would need something with a process like this:

```
1. Someone submits the question anonymously.
2. Question is placed into queue and only people with 
   permissions see the unanswered questions.
3. Once the question is answered by the people with permissions 
   it appears on the page.
4. Older answers are archived and are available in the archive, 
   you could see the last several answers.
```

but I would take whatever is there or I can modify a portlet that is close to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no portlet like you describe.

The closest thing I can think of is using the Message Boards with the Q\A view. However, I'm not certain that anonymous posts are supported.

Comment: May be there is JSR 168 compatible portlet like that, should be a common problem people have. I tried to find some repository of portlets, but it seems there is really no good one. I went through Liferay's repository on their website but there is nothing there that is similar. The closest one I saw was here: http://wiki.exoplatform.com/xwiki/bin/view/KS/FAQ%20Manual